# A C++ program to output all the numbers in a .txt file with a specific number of digits when the number of digits is entered

Tags: c++

Using this code I can extract all the numbers of a text file to another text file. But what I want to achieve is that I want to input the number of digits of the numbers that i want to extract and then only extract those numbers containing the no. of digits I inputted.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
bool isStop(char c);
int main()
{   fstream fin;
    fstream fout;
    string s;
    char a,b=' ';
    fin.open("TheFileThatContainsData.txt", ios::in);
    fout.open("Numbers.txt", ios::out);
    while(fin.get(a))
    {   if(isdigit(a) || isStop(b))
        {   s+=a;
            while(fin.get(a) && isdigit(a))
            {   s+=a;
            }
            if(isStop(a) || fin.eof())
            {   for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
                {   fout.put(s[i]);
                }
                fout.put('\n');
            }
        }
        s.clear();
        b=a;
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
bool isStop(char c)
{
    return (c==' ' || c=='.' || c==',' || c=='(' || c==')' || c=='!' || c=='?' || c=='\n');
}
```

Comment: Please describe in detail the difference of the shown codes behaviour and what you want to achieve. What have you done to pinpoint the misbehaving part?

Comment: Using this code I can extract all the numbers of a text file to another text file. But what I want to achieve is that I want to input the number of digits of the numbers that i want to extract and then only extract those numbers containing the no. of digits I inputted.

Comment: Please [edit] that info into the question.

Comment: `if(isdigit(a) && isStop(b))` doesn't make sense, since both sides of the `&&` can't be true at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your code, I suggest your to take a good book about programming 'good practices' and go step by step.

Here is a code that makes what you ask:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{   
    using std::string;
    using std::stringstream;

    string input="1 123 . 12 12 12345 1 12 123 123456 123 123 1234";
    stringstream fin(input); //replace by file stream if needed
    stringstream fout; // replace by file stream if needed

    constexpr size_t digitsFilter=2;

    while (fin.good())
    {
        // Trim non-digits
        while(fin.good() && !std::isdigit(fin.peek()))
        {
            fin.get();
        }

        // Get number
        unsigned number=0;
        fin >> number;

        // Filter by length
        if (std::to_string(number).size() == digitsFilter)
        {
            fout << number << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << fout.rdbuf();

    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/HJL2h5D3I

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run the above code "14|error: 'constexpr' was not declared in this scope|"

Comment: constexpr is a keyword. Check the link to an online compiler I added. Also, make sure you are using a ~modern C++ of version 2011 or above.

Comment: Also, if this helps you, please don't forget to accept/vote the answer

Comment: yeah it works but instead of inputting the numbers I need to extract them from a .txt file using file handling......

Comment: A stream is the same whatever is the origin of the data. You can just replace the stringstream by your own working ifstream initialized. I replaced it to allows online compilation & example.